# hiding the scrollbar without disabling it in QGraphicsWebView in qt

Tags: qt

After going through so many posts did something like below.

```
QWebFrame* frame = webView->page()->mainFrame();
frame->setScrollBarPolicy( Qt::Horizontal, Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff );
frame->setScrollBarPolicy( Qt::Vertical, Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff );
```

This code did hide the scrollbar, also it disabled scrolling using downArrow as well.
I want to allow scrolling using mouseWheel or downArrow key but hide scroll bar.

How do I do this.

Thanks in advance.